# python remove elements from a set while iterating it

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I tried to remove elements from a set while iterating it,

```
    matches = defaultdict(list)
    for id_a in indices:
        for id_b in indices:
            if id_a != id_b:
               if similar(id_a, id_b, threshold):
                    matches[id_a] += [id_a, id_b]
                    indices.difference_update({id_a, id_b})

def similar(a,b,threshold=0.7):
    return True if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > threshold else False

indices={'aaabbb', 'aabbb', 'aabb', 'aaa', 'bbb'}
matches = {‘aaabbb’: [‘aabb’, ‘aabbb’]}
```

`indices` is a set, `similar` is a function that checks if `id_a` and `id_b` are similar if so list `defaultdict` `matches` will add `id_a:[id_a, id_b]` to it.

but I got an error:

```
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

I am wondering how to fix it and also achieve the goal.

Comment: why you are checking whether 2 elements in a set equal or not? 2 elements in a set can never be equal!

Comment: General rule: don't alter a container while iterating it. Add the "to be deleted" elements in another set and when done iterating, just subtract  it from the original.

Comment: show sample input and expect output.

Comment: @CristiFati I was trying to do a single pass iteration, so remove elements that are similar from `indices` and then continue the iteration, until the outer loop finishes

Comment: @raviraja: `id_a` and `id_b` could easily be the same element. The inner loop isn't going to automatically skip whatever element the outer loop is on.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul have added samples and desired output

Comment: Note: you have 2 nested loops That's O(n\*\*2). also text: *will add `id_a:[id_a, id_b]` to it*, and example `matches = {‘aaabbb’: [‘aabb’, ‘aabbb’]}` don't quite match. It's still unclear (for me) what you're really trying to achieve, but you might take look at *itertools*.